# InstallShield Show product name + version in Add/Remove Programs

Tags: version, installshield, addremoveprograms

How to show product name + version like "My product 1.1.1.0" in Add/Remove Programs, 
Where "My Product" is name of product in InstallShield and "1.1.1.0" Product Version?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design, if you click the link "Click here for support information" it will show you the ProductVersion, Publisher and so on.  I've always found it funny that Windows creates it one way and yet the whole world wants to take it another way including other groups at Microsoft.   Personally I go with best practices and never put version information into my product name but if you want to do it, that's what you'll want to do.

ProductName:  My Product 1.1.1

ProductVersion: 1.1.1.0

This is especially useful if you allow side by side installations of your product.  I.E. change ProductCode and UpgradeCode and transform INSTALLDIR with each release:

C:\ProgramFiles\Company\Product\1.0

C:\ProgramFiles\Company\Product\2.0

Answer (score 2):

Following link contains a fair bit of info regarding add/remove programs:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/09/178342.aspx

And also Installshield Knowledge Base document Q211246 has details.

Comment: Where would I find Q211246? Google doesn't yield any results.

Answer (score 1):

Long ago I worked with old version of instal shield. As it turned out - I wasn't able to modify the product version. Tried editing from installShield UI, tried editing from the ISCmdBld.exe -p "project.ism" -y "13.23.12.1" - but in my version ISCmdBld.exe didn't support -y parameter.
Nothing worked and I needed to do it fast.

So here is my hard core brutal and stupid version how to change the product version, when nothing else helps:
open your .ism project with notepad, find the version text and changed it there. Then build the project with install shield and feel free to be happy.
Product version was near by PATH_TO_LIB_FILES parameter as far as I remember.

I would like to make it clear: My approach is practically the worst one. You shouldn't do anything like that unless it's an emergency.